# "Years of professional coding experience by developer type" is clearly wrong

Tags: bug, survey-2022

https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#section-experience-years-of-professional-coding-experience-by-developer-type

The average student apparently has nearly five years of professional coding experience.

Presumably what you're actually showing is total coding experience, not professional.

Comment: is it not possible for a student to have professional coding experience? What exactly is considered "professional" coding experience? any coding done on a job that isn't training or internship? The question was very open to interpretation.

Comment: I think the confusion here is that the question below it, where we asked about current job, also allows multi-select. It is possible to select both student and a profession, for those who are currently working but continuing to go to school for additional knowledge.

Comment: @KevinB all the other numbers are far higher than they should be, if the two questions  above (Years coding, Years coding professionally) are accurate.

Comment: They are only as accurate as people's ability to interpret what professional coding means.

Comment: @KevinB I don't think he's questioning whether the numbers behind the data are accurate based on interpretation. But that looking at the question above, 28.43% of respondents said they had professional coded for 1-4 years, yet in this question also referencing professional coding, every single profession, even student, is over 4 years, which is hard to comprehend when near a third of respondents had 4 or less years of professional experience.

Comment: While my career in political philosophy went nowhere and ultimately flamed out, I spent five years writing C code to put food on the table. Then I went back to school to formally learn programming, but I can assure you I was in the minority, not the majority, at that school.

Comment: At least in my country around 3/4 of the CS students work part-time during their education. Someone who finishes their master degree and has 5 years of professional experience is not uncommon. Add to that the number of students who study extra occupational and have a few years of experience when they start studying and PHD students, 5 years experience doesn't sound that wrong. Especially because we talk about average: I'm working at a university and am a PHD student with ~15 years professional coding. I alone make up for two students with 0 years, if you want an average of 5 years.

Comment: [Students made an average of $21,768 per year getting that experience](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#section-salary-salary-by-developer-type), so that seems consistent, anyway.

Comment: That's pretty good money. Back in my day we were lucky to earn shiny stones we could trade for gruel.